# Present for bicycle traveler

Tags: bicycles, south-america, gifts

A friend of mine is about to go on a one person multi month trip with his bicycle through South America. Before he leaves, we want to give him a present for his upcoming birthday. The straight forward way would be to ask him, what he needs, but we would like to surprise him if possible.

One idea would be make him a laminated photograph of us and best wishes as a lucky charm. Do you know presents that will be useful and will be likely to suit a bicycle traveler.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your friend, but I prefer useful gifts, especially before a long trip where any extra weight might be a problem.

Does your friend have all the gear he'll need for the trip? I found [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/28934/what-to-prepare-for-a-long-distance-ride-1600km) on Bicycles SE about gear for a long bike trip. You could check if he's got all the needed resources and give him any he might have forgotten.

Another suggestion is for you to give him something that might help him in the countries he'll cycle by, like a (small) dictionary of spanish or portuguese, depending on the countries he intends to go.